# how can I remove php extension using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

http://localhost/omsi_site/blogs.html?title=Responsive%20web%20design

I want to remove `blogs.html?title=` from this url using htaccess.

Comment: Check this web site http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: I have placed .htaccess into omsi_site folder

Comment: I have tried lots of URL rewrite rules in .htaccess but I am stuck now. I have to change this URL:

Comment: blogs.html?title=Responsive%20web%20design

to

blogs/Responsive%20web%20design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code your path will be `/blogs`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /omsi_site/

RewriteRule ^blogs$ blogs.html?title=Responsive%20web%20design [L]
```

Comment: where have you placed the .htaccess?

Comment: i have placed .htaccess in omsi_site folder

Comment: it should work.. are you sure that the extension is .html? in the title of the question you wrote .php

Comment: yes actual file extension is .php but i have changed into.html extension using htaccess

Answer (score 0):

•Log into your cPanel.

• Find the Files category and click on the File Manager icon.

• In the top right hand corner, click on Settings. For the primary domain, click on the Web Root radio button. For addon domains, click on the dropdown and find your desired addon domain name. Be sure the checkbox next to Show Hidden Files is checked. Click the Save button to return to the main File Manager screen.

• You should now be in the root folder of the domain you chose. Look for the .htaccess file and right click on it. This brings up a menu. Find and click on the Edit option. If you get a popup box, simply find and click the Edit button in the lower right corner to continue to the editor.

• You are now in the text editor

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Paste the code and save !